# Factoring a polynomial with big integer coefficients and some known factors.

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I have the following polynomial that I want to factor
$$
\begin{align*}
p(x)=
&- 236364091 x^{13}- 28363690920 x^{12}- 1487737229594 x^{11}\\
&- 44880832661940 x^{10} - 860924276925225 x^9- 10941278514219396 x^8 \\
&- 92883153994532540 x^7 - 516122234647942344 x^6 - 1766587850009264989 x^5 \\
&- 3172232270188300464 x^4 - 1263789594225408906 x^3 + 3700632893619477564 x^2 \\
&+ 3120329011246701345 x+5179915266025500 \\
\end{align*}
$$
I suspect that $(x+24)$ and $(x+25)$ are factors. I'm interested in the remaining polynomial $q(x)$ such that $p(x)=(x+24)(x+25)q(x)$. I've tryed Mathematica with no success. Can anyone help?

I'm also interested in other software packages more suited to the factorization of this kind of polynomials.

Thanks.

---

I'm back!!!

Unfortunately there was an error in the above polynomial, so it didnt factor as expected. The correct one follows
$$
\begin{align*}
p(x)= 
&-2363640910 x^{13}- 283636909200 x^{12}- 14830715886140 x^{11} \\
&-445215783064800 x^{10}- 8492530754498370 x^9- 107310315789497520 x^8 \\
&- 905953817318009480 x^7-  5008244551318927680 x^6- 17061651312407299570 x^5\\
&-  30494240185050800880 x^4- 12007914756669549180 x^3 + 35636084573032450080 x^2\\
&+ 29908147265568403650 x +103598305320510000   
\end{align*}
$$
and factors as expected to:
$$
\begin{align*} 
p(x)=-10 (24 + x) (25 + x) q(x)
\end{align*}
$$
where
$$
\begin{align*} 
q(x)=&236364091 x^{11}+ 16781850461 x^{10}+518942461425 x^9\\
&+ 9024287420055 x^8 + 95697515012142 x^7+ 627280891321794 x^6\\
&+ 2440109049747842 x^5+ 4890576901172110 x^4+ 2461433234591367 x^3\\
&- 5532350693162895 x^2- 4983281122883427 x-17266384220085
\end{align*}
$$
Thanks, next time I'll think twice...

Comment: This is an evil, devilish polynomial, yet...can't Mathematica check whether $\,-25\,,\,-24\,$ are roots of your polynomial? If they are then dividing by their factors' product should be relatively easy even for less powerful programms...

Comment: How did you come across this polynomial?

Comment: Factor over what field ?

Comment: The polynimal evaluates to $22423918741962280042500$ at $x=-24$, and to $75358418484740751360000$ at $x=-25$, so neither $x+24$ nor $x+25$ are factors. The $\gcd$ of these evaluations is $2^2.3^5.5^4.7.11.13.103$. Did you by any chance just know about divisibility modulo some number?

Comment: Hell... I've to check everithing again... It should really be $0$ at $x=-24$ and $x=-25$, I'll be back...

Answer (score 1):

This function has no factorization in $\mathbb{Q}$. I did a manual check with Mathematica.